# MySQL Fill multiple unused rows with data in a table with pre-populated data

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with pre-populated data that looks similar to this:

| Id | giftCode | userId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AGiftCode | 42342 |
| 2 | AnotherCode | NULL |
| 3 | AnotherOne | NULL |
| 4 | Code | NULL |
| 5 | Code2 | NULL |
| 6 | Code3 | NULL |

Multiple users are simultaneously assigned to the pre-populated data at certain times, and I am currently achieving this using the following query multiple times:

```
UPDATE table SET userId = "xxxxx" WHERE userId is NULL LIMIT 1
```

Is there a way to do the same thing, but with a single UPDATE statement to insert x number of userId's into the next x number of open rows?

Only the userIds to insert and the number of userIds to be inserted is known at the point of updating.

Comment: Your query is wrong - LIMIT without unique ORDER BY is not deterministic and hence makes no sense.

Comment: @Akina In this case, it actually doesn't matter, because the OP has no preference for which code gets selected.

Comment: *Only the userIds to insert and the number of userIds to be inserted is known at the point of updating.* You must provide the list of `userid` values not as values list but as a rowset into the query. or you must convert the list to rowset in the query (by recursive CTE, JSON_TABLE and so on).

Answer (score 0):

One approach uses `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`:

```sql
SELECT giftCode FROM yourTable WHERE userId IS NULL LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE yourTable SET userId = 'xxxxx' WHERE giftCode = 'code from above';
```

Comment: Imagine that `giftCode` is not unique... I do not see the guarantee that selected and updated row is the same one in this case.

Comment: @Akina ... I'm not imagining that at all.  The gift codes can be assumed to be some kind of UUID.

Comment: I believe this would have the same result as my current query (setting the userId for the first unused row found), unless I am missing something? I want a way to provide x number of userIds to insert it into x number of unused rows in a single UPDATE.

Comment: But then wouldn't I still need to do x number of UPDATEs for each userId/giftCode?

Comment: AFAIK there is no avoiding multiple updates for multiple gift codes.  But, why are you opposed to that?

Comment: Not particularly opposed, was just wondering if there was a way to do it in one update.